# Prove that number $\sqrt{2}$ is an irrational number using this theorem "if $a^2$ is even, $a$ must be even"

Tags: solution-verification, radicals, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, rationality-testing

I have to prove the following:

> Prove $\sqrt{2}$ is an irrational number using this theorem "if $a^2$ is even, $a$ must be even"

I made a proof by contradiction for the statement above, but I believed that there is a mistake in my proof. 
Suppose $\sqrt{2}$ is a rational number,
let a = $\sqrt{2}$
\begin{align}
 a = \sqrt{2}\\
 a^2 = 2 
\end{align}
Therefore, $a^2$ is even 
Given that if $a^2$ is even, $a$ must be even,

but $\sqrt{2}$ is not even
Hence, we have a contradiction that if $a^2$ is even, $a$ must be even
Thus, $\sqrt{2}$ is an irrational number

Question: Would someone mind pointing out where my mistake is and why it is a mistake?
Thank you for your kind attention

Comment: " is/is not even" means nothing for non integers like $\sqrt{2}$ or like your *rational* number $a.$

Comment: Thanks. I get it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prove the statement so you can see how this kind of proofs are done:

For the sake of contradiction, suppose that $\sqrt{2}$ is rational. We can write
$$\sqrt{2}=\frac{p}{q},$$
where $p,q$ are integers and the RHS fraction is irreducible. Squaring both sides and multiplying by $q^2$ we get
$$2q^2=p^2.$$
Since, $2q^2$ is even then $p^2$ is even. Can you follow from here?

Comment: Because "if $a^2$ is even, $a$ must be even", p is even. Since p is even, there is an integer $n$ that $p = 2n$. We can obtain $2q^2 = 4n^2$, then $q^2 = 2n^2$. Thus, q is even. But as the RHS fraction is irreducible, p and q are not both even. Hence, there is a contradiction. Is it reasonable?

Comment: That's perfect!